# Tracking time spent viewing email in Google Analytics via a tracking pixel

Tags: email, google-analytics

So I'm experimenting with tracking email activity through Google Analytics.

I can create a simple tracking pixel that indicates if the email has been opened and sends that event to GA like so:

```
<img src="https://google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-0000000000-1&cid=555%ec=Email&ea=OpenedEmail"/>
```

But is there a way to send a hit to GA that records user timing?

I can see user timing variables in GA's Measurement Protocol: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#utc so I assume it would be a second tracking pixel (first sends open event to GA) like this:

```
<img src="https://google-analytics.com/collect?v1&t=timing&cid=555&utc=Email&utv=EMAIL NAME&utt"/>
```

Since utt is an integer, I shouldn't hard code it with anything right?

Has anyone else attempted this?